# Upgrading kernel on OpenVZ VPS

Tags: kernel, openvz

I am trying to install docker on my OpenVZ VPS. I have discovered that my kernel is not up to date, as I am running 2.6.32-042stab123.9 and need to upgrade it.

I have updated to 17.04, however the kernel did not update in the process.

I also tried to update manually following [this guide on howtoforge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-linux-kernel-in-ubuntu-1604-server/)

However I get the error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/ploop35399p1'.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ahh that's what it looks like. Is it possible to run docker on this type of visualization? 

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know that, but you can either edit your question to make it clear that that is what you want to do (change the title, especially), or let this one be closed as a duplicate and ask a new question :)